# Using manual referencing with MongoDB and PHP

Tags: php, mongodb

I have 2 collections:

'Users' collection

```
_id: ObjectID('56c9a824f4b233dfd30041b3')
name: Luke Skywalker
username: jedimaster23
```

and

'projectInfo'collection

```
_id: 56d1d830f4b233ded30041c3
projectName: L
startDate: 24 April 2016
users_id: ObjectID('56c0abb7f4b233ba020041b3')
saved_at: February 27, 2016 5:09 PM
```

each time a user creates a project their user ID is stored in the projectInfo collection as well as the users collection so there is a manual reference in the projectInfo collection called user_id.

I am trying just to list all projects created by each user.  The query I have at the moment is:

```
    $userTest = $user->_id; // get the userid from the current session

    $findResult = $usersCollection->findOne(array('_id'=> new MongoID($userTest)), array('user_id'=>1));//get current user

    $result = $collection->find(array('_id' => array('$in' => $findResult['user_id'])));
```

However, this does not return any records although I know that the user I am logged in as has created many projects.

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong, this is my first project with MongoDB so still at the learning stage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why not like this:

```
 $currentUserId = $user->_id; // get the userid from the current session

 $result = $projectCollection->find(array('users_id' => new MongoID($currentUserId));
```

---

updated to more simple solution